# ASP.NET C# Webcam Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webcam

I'm curious, how do you integrate a webcam with an ASP.NET C# application in a 'live broadcast' type scenario? I have no idea where to start with this but really interested to learn how it works in terms of detection and live streaming. A point in the right direction would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC really. The camera's on the client, so you need to use client scripting such as Flash or Silverlight to access it. Here's for example a [jquery plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) (based on Flash) which allows you to control the camera (once the client authorizes the site to do so).

HTML5 might also be an option one day.

Comment: Is there any alternative to flash or silverlight? Not keen on either of these technologies due to plugin dependencies.

Comment: Those are the most popular and widely supported. Don't expect to be able to manipulate the camera on the client machine from your server without a plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm asking for too much really, next I'll want it mobile compatible. Ill give the JQuery flash plugin a go I think, thanks.